# Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex episode viewing order?

Tags: suggested-order, ghost-in-the-shell, ghost-in-the-shell-sac

I got partway through Ghost in the Shell: Stand Alone Complex a while ago and would like to start again. There are two types of episodes: "Stand Alone" and "Complex". The latter has on ongoing plot, the former seem to be, well, stand-alone. They're listed categorized, but without spoilers (except for episode 1 in the discussion probably), on this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/3iz08m/spoilers_ghost_in_the_shell_stand_alone_complex/).

Does watching them in episode order make sense, or would be better to watch all of the stand-alone episodes, then all of the "complex" episodes (or vice-versa)? This is probably somewhat opinionated, but I'm wondering if there's a consensus in the fan community (can't look without seeing spoilers) or if there actually is content or references shared between them that will only make sense in episode order.

Answer (score 1):

Most of SAC season 1 is Section 9 trying to figure out just what's going on. There are a lot of side stories to the main storyline, so in terms of impact you might be able to get away with skipping an episode here or there (S1E12 "SA: Tachikoma Runs Away; The Movie Director's Dream – ESCAPE FROM" would be one of them), but the main storyline is a rolling one, so I wouldn't advise trying to watch them out of order.

Comment: I think that episode illustrates how even episodes that aren't part of the primary plot still continue the ongoing narrative, since the way the tachikomas change is important but could feel fast or undeveloped without the side stories. I think some of Togusa's character development is similar.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not saying that skipping episodes is a good thing here. None of the SAC series have filler episodes, but some episodes have less impact on the storyline than others.

Answer (score 0):

I watched them in their original order, so I can't say what would be missed if I watched the different types of episodes separately. However, if you are the kind of person that loves an uninterrupted plot, there exists an edited movie version called 'Ghost in the Shell: S.A.C. - The Laughing Man'. It only contains scenes from episode one and the 'complex' episodes.